# DCOM needs to register server on both client and server computer

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, dcom

I have written in Delphi 2010 a DCOM server and a client to call the server. To be able to run the client on a different machine than the server's machine, I need to register the server on both machines, beside to do the security related things to allow the client to access the server.

I am wondering if there is someone to know the way that needs the minimum effort to use a client and a server on two different machines, supposing that both of client and server are written and they are working. What I got so far is as follows:

1. run the server.exe on server machine: server.exe /regserver
2. run DCOMCNFG and set the security settings on server machine.
3. define incoming rules in firewall to let the connection on server machine.
4. run the server.exe on client machine: server.exe /regserver
5. now we can run the client.exe on client machine and use the server's implemented interfaces.

What pushed me to write this question is that I can't understand why we need to register the server on client machine also. The client application know about the interface and server GUIDs and use them accordingly when creating the server in its implementation. So the DCOM on client machine has enough information to query the DCOM of the server machine to provide it with the correct server having the provided GUID, and we do not need to register server on client side (at least as it seems), but we need to actually do it.

best regards,

Comment: The client may know everything it needs to know but ultimately it is not the client that sets up the connection with the other side, COM+ does that. So the type library needs to be registered on the client machine before the middleware can do its magic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I tought I might be missing something in my settings, and as you said, it is this way by design, and there is not anything wrong with my way of settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't have to register the server on the client machine. However, you might need to register the server Type library on the client machine. You have 2 options:

1. Register the server's type library on the client machine
2. Create a DataSnap Server application (COM-based) and use
   DCOMConnection, SocketConnection or SOAPConnection to connect to it
   without registering the server nor the type library on the client
   machine.

I've developed several COM/COM+ servers in the last 15+ years. My recommendation is: Create a DataSnap COM Based servers and save yourself a lot of headache when deploying your COM server and client. It is much easier to deploy and maintain.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Registering the type library is something like registering server itself, it is in contrast of what I expected. But using DataSnap is in the direction of what I thought. May be the DataSnap has completed the DCOM in this perspective.

Comment: Actually registering the type library has the same effect that registering the server but, of course, is not the same. When registering the type library I don't have to deploy the binary version of my server to get it registered. I just need to send a TLB file with my client EXE, which can check the registry and register itself the TLB file only if needed (for which it will require elevation in most cases).

Comment: As always you are right, they are not the same in technical term. But my view was on the way we are acting, registering on both parties or just registering on server side, and letting the foundation do the rest. In the DataSnap way you proposed, we just lay the client.exe to the client, and I don't need to register anything more on the client side. I hope to be clear this time. Actually referring back to my question, when DataSnap can do this, why on earth DCOM can't do the same. I thank you anyway to help me.